# Singular Jekyll post anomaly not rendering

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have been searching around for a solution to this but I have come up with nothing pertaining to my specific case.

**Problem:** a single Jekyll post is not showing up.

**Details:**

- It is a Github Pages site that I push to, so I do not render the Jekyll myself
- Another post in the same push to Github is visible and just fine
- It is in the same folder as many other posts that published (specifically a sub-folder under _posts)
- The front-matter is formatted the same way as all the other posts that published
- The date of the post is not in the future
- There are no illegal hidden characters I can find within the file
- The name of the file is properly formatted
- There is a post published *after* the post in question that *is* working properly and I made sure to clear my cache

**Context:** It is a personal D&D related site so forgive the weird content, but here is the paste of the file. The file is named "2016-11-10-teacup-of-the-tempest.md"

```
---
title: Teacup of the Tempest
item_id: 88
category: Wondrous
item_subtypes:
  - Breastplate
  - Half Plate
item_rarity: Very Rare
item_attunement: true
item_requirement: by a Barbarian
item_curse: false
item_classes:
  - Barbarian
item_school: Evocation
item_role:
  - Attack
item_damage:
  - Bludgeoning
tags:
  - Exhaustion
  - Rage
  - Dexterity
  - Strength
  - Aura
  - Bludgeoning
item_idea:
item_co_creator:
item_updated:
last_modified_at:
---

This delicate white teacup is fit for a nobleman, but will not chip or crack. It has been rumored to have been originally found when it was flung through a window, carried from a shipment of china by a violent storm. While you are attuned to the teacup you can gain up to 5 charges that can be used to activate the magic of the teacup.

### Calm Before the Storm
During a short rest if you drink tea from this teacup you regain all expended charges and your exhaustion decreases by 1 level. The tea can be of any type but must be hot when you drink it. You also regain 1 charge each long rest that you take.

### Cyclone
As an action while raging you can expend a charge to attack your enemies with the strength of the storm. As the winds swirl around you you make long sweeping attacks at all enemies within 5 feet. All hostile creatures within range must make a Dexterity saving throw with a DC equal to 8 + your proficiency + your strength modifier. On a failed save they take damage equivalent to two of your weapon attacks.

### Heart of the Storm
When you activate your rage you can choose to expend all 5 charges to release the full power of the tempest. A 20-foot radius sphere of whirling air springs into existence centered on you that follows you until your rage ends. Each creature (not including you) that ends its turn in the sphere must succeed a Strength saving throw with a DC equal to 8 + your proficiency + your strength modifier. On a failed save they take 2d6 bludgeoning damage. Additionally, the sphere’s space is difficult terrain for all creatures besides you.
```

By all accounts it should be rendering but it is not, even though there are no Github errors.

> note: It is not rendering in the pages I have rendering posts by tag or manually accessible by going to the url either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your site locally, you will see that you have five files that are producing an ***"Error: could not read file /path/to/file: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"***, because they have a **Western (Windows 1252)** encoding and not an **UTF-8 without BOM** encoding.

Ensure that :

- *wondrous/2016-11-07-urn-of-the-lava-bearer.md*,
- *wondrous/2016-11-10-teacup-of-the-tempest.md*,
- *ring/2016-11-16-ring-of-the-golden-defender.md*,
- *weapon/2016-11-16-lead-hex-crossbow.md*,
- and *wand/2016-11-03-staff-of-thundering-orbs.md*

are **UTF-8 without BOM** encoded.

Comment: Wow, you went through a lot of trouble to get me an answer on this one. I didn't expect anyone to go find my site and pull it just to try and troubleshoot it for me. Thank you so much, I will make sure to check this when I run into problems in the future!